# Одинакова высота внутренних элементов

Tags: html, css3, flexbox, grid

Здравствуйте имеется вот такой блок, заголовки в нем могут отличатся по количеству строк соответственно декоративный разделитель может съезжать. Вопрос в следующем если в CSS(не JS) способ задать вышину всех заголовков по самому большому из них?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**Пример 1** (при условии, что нижний текст содержит одинаковое кол-во строк )

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card__dot {
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.card__text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="card__title">Title</h3>
    <div class="card__dot"></div>
    <p class="card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolore ea, placeat repellendus velit maxime dolores sint minima harum dolorem sequi, molestiae atque eveniet asperiores reiciendis cupiditate maiores. Enim, asperiores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="card__title">Title<br> title</h3>
    <div class="card__dot"></div>
    <p class="card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolore ea, placeat repellendus velit maxime dolores sint minima harum dolorem sequi, molestiae atque eveniet asperiores reiciendis cupiditate maiores. Enim, asperiores.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="card__title">Title</h3>
    <div class="card__dot"></div>
    <p class="card__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolore ea, placeat repellendus velit maxime dolores sint minima harum dolorem sequi, molestiae atque eveniet asperiores reiciendis cupiditate maiores. Enim, asperiores.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Пример 2**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th,
table td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: .5rem;
}

table th {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  text-align: left;
}

table .dot {
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Title <br> title</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dot"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="dot"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="dot"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolore ea, placeat repellendus velit maxime dolores sint minima harum dolorem sequi, molestiae atque eveniet asperiores reiciendis cupiditate maiores. Enim, asperiores.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat dolore ea, placeat repellendus velit maxime dolores sint minima harum dolorem sequi, molestiae atque eveniet asperiores reiciendis cupiditate maiores. Enim, asperiores.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

ответ как бы на поверхности. отказаться от flex в пользу grid

```css
#x{
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 2em auto; /* !!! */
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 5px;
}

/* остальной css лишь для подсветки границ */
#x{--border: red;}
p{--border: green;}
b{--border: blue;}
p, b, #x{
border: 1px solid var(--border);
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'>
  <b>h 1</b>
  <b>h 2</b>
  <b>h 3</b>
  <b>h 4</b>
<p>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa
</p>
<p>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa
</p>
<p>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
aaaaaaaaaaa
</p>
<p>
aaaaaaaaaaa<br/>
</p>
</div>
```

а вообще, заголовки у вас судя по скрину ведут себя крайне странно. будто им специально через :nth-child метрики рандомизировали... вставьте код для ясности что-ли...